# bcdedit mistake while trying to set up boot to vhd in windows 7. any way to fix this?

Tags: windows-7, boot, vhd, bcdedit

so yeah i made a mistake in bcdedit when attempting to set up boot to vhd (which i have done 50 times on this box for temporary SP dev env). This time around after I did my routine and restart....nothing after dell splash....so I am guessing I hosed the boot? If I had to guess on what I did this time is after I copied the current entry for the new GUID, I didn't run my /set cmds on the new GUID :(

Is there anyway to correct this or am I just completely done with the original OS? That would be pretty awful, so I am hoping there is some crazy work around to get it back?

windows 7
appreciated as always

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boot from the Windows DVD, go to the `Repair Options` and let Windows fix the issues. You can also use Bootrec to fix the MBR and BCD:

```
Bootrec /rebuildbcd
```

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927391

Comment: @magicandre1981...thanks, will this allow me to get the original OS I started the process from back (and basically all my files)?

Comment: @Justin: Yes, bootrec's `/rebuildbcd` option (and others like `/scanos` if required) should fix your BCD store and let you regain access to Windows. Also see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927392.

Comment: yes, this brings Windows back to be able to boot. Now you have to add all other Boot entries again. Use EasyBCD or VisualBCD Editor if you don't want to mess the BCD again.